# What is the equivalent for ENABLE keyword in Oracle for Microsoft SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

The keyword 'ENABLE' in Oracle is used in the following way

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
(
    Emp_id NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    Emp_name VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
    CONSTRAINT "FEED_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("EMP_ID")
)
```

To convert above query to SQL Server - what should I replace the keyword `ENABLE` with? Or should I not mention it at all in the query for SQL Server?

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
(
    Emp_id NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL ________ ,
    Emp_name VARCHAR(500),
    CONSTRAINT "FEED_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("EMP_ID")
)
```

Comment: You posted how it's written, not how it's used. What are you trying to do? If whatever `ENABLE` does isn't needed, you can simply omit it

Comment: I think constraints are enabled by default, even in Oracle. You don't need to enable them explicitly.

Comment: Also, `NUMBER(10,0)` probably translates best as `INT` even if the ranges aren't exactly the same.

Comment: Yep, you can replace it with nothing, as this [answer says](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57125/6381)